# How to split a big dataframe into smaller dataframes based on columns in big dataframe spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a big dataframe with schema

Now I need to convert this big dataframe into multiple dataframes based on (event_start_date_time,service_key) and then keep that multiple dataframes in a List so that I can use them from the List

The big dataframe is having 30 distinct (event_start_date_time,service_key)

I need a small dataframe_1 that contains records with event_start_date_time='2018-03-05T11:00:00Z' and service_key='1234'

I need a small dataframe_2 that contains records with event_start_date_time='2018-03-06T11:00:00Z' and service_key='1235'

...

I need  bigdataframe to List[DataFrame] = List(dataframe_1 ,dataframe_2 ,dataframe_3, dataframe_4,... dataframe_30)

I need small dataframes because my requirement is about to do more transformations on those each smaller dataframe and then store the result as a file for each smaller dataframe in HDFS separately

At the moment what I am doing is I wrote code that gives me List of unique (event_start_date_time,service_key) and I loop that List to apply the respective filter , but it is taking too much time

my code :

```
 val df = /* Big Dataframe creation logic*/
 val uniqueContentList = getUniqueContents(df)


  def getUniqueContents(df: DataFrame) : List[String] = {

  df
  .select("event_start_date_time","service_key")
  .removeDuplicates()
  .withColumn("unique_content",concat(df("event_start_date_time"),lit("_"),df("service_key"))).drop("event_start_date_time").drop("service_key")
  .collect()
  .map(row => row.getString(0))
  .toList
  .sorted

 }



  val dataframeMap = uniqueContentList.map(elem => consolidateProgramIntervals(df, elem))
  val unionedDF = dataframeMap.reduce((df1, df2) => df1.unionAll(df2))


  def consolidateProgramIntervals(df:DataFrame,uniqueContentKey:String) :DataFrame = {

log.info("consolidating ProgramIntervals for " + uniqueContentKey)
val arr = uniqueContentKey.split(("_"))
val eventStartDateTime = arr(0)
val serviceKey = arr(1)

val filteredDF = df
  .filterByUniqueContent(eventStartDateTime,serviceKey)
 filteredDF 


  }
```

Comment: I would not suggest you to form the list of dataframes and use loops but rather I would suggest you to partition dataframes with thoses keys and do the transformations on those partitions and save the partitioned dataframes separately in hdfs.

Comment: @Ramesh  On each Partition the logic is very big such as further filter , joins , unions . I am using spark 1.5 . I heard  that some window functions are available on partition, not user defined functions

Comment: yes you heard it correct. joins are for joining two dataframes and union is for the same purpose. You are trying to separate the existing dataframe and again join or union them? if that is the case, why would you do that and I suggest you to reform your architecture.